# Invalid Token InstaMojo while fetching order Android

Tags: android, payment-gateway, access-token, instamojo

```
private void fetchOrder(String orderID) {
        com.instamojo.android.network.Request request = new com.instamojo.android.network.Request(orderID, new OrderRequestCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onFinish(final Order order, final Exception error) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                   if (error != null) {
                            if (error instanceof Errors.ConnectionError) {
                                showToast("No internet connection");
                            } else if (error instanceof Errors.ServerError) {
                                showToast("Server error. Try again");
                            } else if (error instanceof Errors.AuthenticationError) {
                                Log.e("error",error.toString());
                                showToast("Access token is invalid or expired. Please update the token");
                            } else {
                                showToast(error.toString());
                            }
                            return;
                        }

                        startPreCreatedUI(order);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        request.execute();
    }
```

Order Id I am getting from backend which is correct but failing to get order using the above method
am I missing something in the above method or need to configure?